# Sensitive Data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I am building a CodeIgniter 2.1.3 application that uses the Twitter OAuth API for several functions. I have all my tokens for the Twitter API in a separate file, app_tokens.php, which is ignored by git. What function do I use to include this file in my Tweet class?

app_tokens.php:

```
<?php 
$consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$user_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$user_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/include ?

Comment: Pekka is right...a simple Google search for "include files in PHP" would have shown that one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer in https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: aah you beat me to it by 36 seconds =oP

Comment: +1 Thank you very much Mimo. I had the same problem but your link helped me fix the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called `tweet.php` in your `application/config` folder and put this in it replacing the X's with your real data of course:

```
<?php

$config['consumer_key'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['consumer_secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['user_token'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['user_secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Then in your Tweet class load that config file by doing this:

```
$this->config->load('tweet');
```

Then you can access those config values like so:

```
$this->config->item('consumer_key');
```